# how to get email id through auth0 social login

Tags: angular, auth0, social-authentication

I have integrated auth0 code with my angular 2 application for social auth using the sample code provided at https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/04-user-profile. During social login, Auth0 is not providing me email id for facebook, twitter and linkedin. Can someone suggest how to configure it. I'm not able to find out the crack for it or any better solution than using Auth0.?

Comment: Email is always provided as profile.email, however in case of twitter you'll have to add a rule as twitter does not provide email addresses to applications https://github.com/auth0/rules/blob/master/rules/get-twitter-email.md

Comment: Also you'll need to add the email scope in both Linked in and Facebook connection settings

Comment: Thank you Abhishek, It worked. Please add your comment as answer so that i can mark it right.